# Need to reset form fields of specific fields

Tags: reactjs, antd

How to reset specific form fields in antd.
I using `resetformfields();` but it resets whole form value. I want to reset particular values

Answer (score 0):

In Ant design, you can use `setFieldsvalue` to set particular field values.

```
  form.setFieldsValue({
    fieldName: '',
  });
```